# How to avoid a too cluttered UI on mobile devices?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, mobile-application

[image]

One of the features of my mobile application, is the facility to request a seat on a journey. The user can view details about the journey, and then selects the **"x sharing"** link to pop down information (seen on screen 2) about:

- Who is on the journey (denoted by profile picture)
- Where they are being picked up from
- How much each of them is paying
- The total journey time
- The total journey cost
- The total journey mileage

Now I have 2 questions to ask regarding this UI

1) Is the **2 sharing** link on the first screen too small and unnoticeable? Can I make it more **appearent to the user in anyway**? Note that its different to the **Request Seat** link which takes the user to a different screen.

2) How can I reduce the clutter on the second screen? All of the information is important to have, but it looks a bit messy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's okay to make the "x sharing" link that small for two reasons :

- Some people doesn't really like the idea to share their taxi with unknow folks
- This is first of all an information, not every users care about who is sharing their taxi and nor would they tap the link

**But if your goal is to increase the social part of the app** you could make it visually bigger or try to display the user's profile picture directly on the first screen.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdaP0G.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

That been said, I don't think your second screen is too cluttered. Actually it's well structured with all the informations. You did a great job !

**EDIT** : On the other side, the "Request Seat" should probably be bigger since it is the main action to perform (you could design it as a large button).

*P.S.: I'm wondering if it is really important to show how much the others are paying for the taxi ?*

Answer (score 3):

The "2 sharing" link looks like it fits fine, not too small, but not too big.

If you are going to have something pop out - make  the background dimmed or blurred so the the focus is on the pop-out. This would make it appear less busy.